# how to solve error Xamarin Android player Beta has expired ,Please update

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have created a Helloworld cross platform project from Visual Studio . 
The project builded successfully and while running the android project using the emulator (Nexus4 KitKat Android 4.4 ) I am getting this warning

> Xamarin Android  player Beta has expired ,Please update

And once I press OK I am getting message

> There were deployment errors . Do you want to continue?

How can I fix this issue? Did I missed any components during the installation of xamarin for visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Android player is cancelled officially , so my recommendations for you are three Emulators.

1. **[Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)**: For me this is the best emulator available. However it requires that Hyper-V feature to be enabled.
2. **[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)**: I see this as a better alternative for Xamarin Android Player. However it needs a license.
3. **Android Emulator** which is provided by Android SDK. By default it is a slow emulator however there is a tweek you can do to make it faster:

   - Go and download HAXM from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)
   - Go to your android sdk manager from your visual studio
   - Go down to Extras and install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

By doing this , now you can use the emulators which comes with Android SDK and they are great.